# Unable to show player controls in MPMoviePlayerViewController in ios

Tags: ios, video, uiview, tableview

I am trying to show MPMoviePlayerViewController in table view cell. 
i have initialised it in didselect method of table view cell. Problem is that i cannot see the controls in player like : full screen button and other buttons as shown in this picture:
[image]

Can anyone help me how to implement those controls in player controller ?
Here is my code in didselect method:

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSURL * movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];

self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:movieURL];

self.playerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
self.playerController.moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;


[self.playerController.moviePlayer play];

[self.view addSubview:[self.playerController view]];


}
```

Comment: It would be more user friendly if you show thumb image in you table view cell and use MPMoviePlayerController separately on full screen to show video.

Comment: i want to show in both ways ...in line as well as full screen